# Failed to construct 'Worker' error when using vite@^4.0.0 with Laravel@10.13.5

Tags: laravel, vite

I'm developing a Laravel@10.13.5 project and using vite@^4.0.0 bundler for asset bundling. However, I encountered a problem with a worker dependency in my node_modules directory that cannot be resolved. I'm seeing the following error:

`worker-client.js:15 Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: Failed to construct 'Worker': Script at 'http://127.0.0.1:5173/@fs/{myDir}/node_modules/.vite/deps/worker?type=module&worker_file' cannot be accessed from origin 'http://127.0.0.1:8000'.`

This error is being thrown when attempting to construct a worker, and it seems that the worker script cannot be accessed from the origin of my application.

How can I resolve this issue and successfully create a worker with Vite and Laravel@10.13.5?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.